# Dependence of rate of effusion on quantity present

Tags: diffusion

Graham's law states that rate of effusion (no of molecules moving out of a small hole per unit time) is inversely proportional to the square root of the molecular mass. Why is it not depending on the amount of that substance present in the container?

For example there is a container filled with two different gases. There is vacuum outside the container and a small hole is made. Suppose 99.9999% of the container(by number of moles) is occupied by a really heavy gas(like SO2 or something like that) and the rest is a really lighter gas( say H2).  Common sense suggests SO2 should effuse faster than H2. (I am not meaning complete effusion. Assume taking some short interval of time). But if we go by the Graham's law, H2 will diffuse faster. Can someone explain where I am wrong?

EDIT: I mean won't more SO2  be effused than H2 during the same time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grahams law gives the ratio of effusion of different gases under identical conditions (pressure, temperature, container, hole) and is related to the mean molecular velocity of the molecules and to Avogadro's law, that the same number of molecules occupy the same volume under the same conditions. You are considering an admixture of a very small number of $H_2$ molecules to the $SO_2$ gas in the same container. Therefore the number of different gas molecules is not the same in the volume and you cannot apply Graham's law to their effusion rate.

There will be more $SO_2$ effused than $H_2$ during the same time interval due to the much lower number of $H_2$ in the volume in spite of its larger thermal molecular speed.

Comment: Is there a way I can quantitatively obtain the relative rates of effusion?

Comment: If you assume that the effusion is proportional to the mean thermal velocity of the gas molecule considered, as is done in Grahams law, then, in your case of different number of moles $N_{SO2}$ and $N_{H2}$ in the container,  the relative effusion rate of $H_2$ to $SiO_2$  is given by $$ \frac{E_{H2}}{E_{SO2}}=\frac{N_{H2}}{N_{SO2}}\frac {m_{SO2}}{m_{H2}}$$